# Getting a list of Records with only one related record

Tags: mysql

I need a list of Teams that have only one member.

The sql:

```
CREATE  TABLE `formsfiles`.`Teams` (
  `ID` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,
  `Name` VARCHAR(45) NULL ,
  PRIMARY KEY (`ID`) );


INSERT INTO `Teams` (`Name`) VALUES ('Sharks');
INSERT INTO `Teams` (`Name`) VALUES ('Jets');
INSERT INTO `Teams` (`Name`) VALUES ('Fish');
INSERT INTO `Teams` (`Name`) VALUES ('Dodgers');
INSERT INTO `Teams` (`Name`) VALUES ('Pigs');

CREATE  TABLE `Players` (
  `ID` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,
  `Name` VARCHAR(45) NULL ,
  `Team_ID` INT NULL ,
  PRIMARY KEY (`ID`) );

INSERT INTO `Players` (`Name`, `Team_ID`) VALUES ('Jim', '1');
INSERT INTO `Players` (`Name`, `Team_ID`) VALUES ('Tom', '1');
INSERT INTO `Players` (`Name`, `Team_ID`) VALUES ('Harry', '2');
INSERT INTO `Players` (`Name`, `Team_ID`) VALUES ('Dave', '2');
INSERT INTO `Players` (`Name`, `Team_ID`) VALUES ('Tim', '3');
INSERT INTO `Players` (`Name`, `Team_ID`) VALUES ('Trey', '4');
INSERT INTO `Players` (`Name`, `Team_ID`) VALUES ('Jay', '4');
INSERT INTO `Players` (`Name`, `Team_ID`) VALUES ('Steve', '4');
INSERT INTO `Players` (`Name`, `Team_ID`) VALUES ('Ziggy', '5');
INSERT INTO `Players` (`Name`, `Team_ID`) VALUES ('Chris', '4');
```

I should get the answer

```
ID     Name
3      Fish
5      Pigs
```

(This is the inverse of a previously asked question:  Kindly don't beat me down!)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT t.ID, t.Name
FROM Teams t
JOIN Players p ON t.ID=p.Team_ID
GROUP BY t.ID
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT p.ID) = 1;
```

Comment: You don't need the distinct or p.id in the count - count(*) will do, because it's an inner join

Comment: Yes, you're right, in this case, it's a one-to-many relationship so that would be sufficient.

Comment: I mentioned it because I believe strongly in using the minimal amount of code whenever possible (caveats like readability notwithstanding). Among other things, less code = less bugs IMHO

Answer (score 2):

```
select t.id, t.name
from teams t
join players p on p.team_id = t.id
group by t.id, t.name
having count(*) = 1
```